# Auto-Populating a Form Using a button with Radio Options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I was wondering if it is possible to fill out a form by clicking a button that displays a list of radio buttons that you would select one from that would fill out the form with the selection and fields you have made. As of now, I have made the form, with a button and the required data(JSON), however, I would like to utilize all of these into one. Some code for example would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>This is my title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Example</a></h1>
        <form id="form" class="myForm"  method="post" action="get.php">
        <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Example</h2>
            <p>Please Fill Out the Fields Below.</p>

        </div>                      
        <ul >


        <li id="profile">
        <label class="description" for="">Please select your profile by clicking the button or continuing below:
        </label>
        <div>
            <input id="profilebutton" type="button" name="prof" class="button_text" value="Select Profile">
        </div>
        </li>


        <!--First Name Input--> 

        <li id="FirstName" >
        <label class="description" for="firstname">First Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       

        <!--Last Name Input-->

        <li id="LastName" >
        <label class="description" for="lastname">Last Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>


        <li id="age" >
        <label class="description" for="age">Age </label>
        <div>
            <input id="age" name="age" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       



        <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id"  />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" class="button_text" id="resetForm" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </li>
            </ul>

        </form> 

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And then for instance, when you click the button, it would either re-direct you to another page, or display a page containing the information that you would select and it would populate the fields. For example, the data would look like:

```
{
    "CASE1": {
        "FNAME": "Joe",
        "LNAME": "Schmo",
        "AGE": "45",
        "SEX": "M",
        "ID": "1"
    },
    "CASE2": {
        "FNAME": "John",
        "LNAME": "Snow",
        "AGE": "23",
        "SEX": "M",
        "ID": "2"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using jquery. The basic idea being, when you click the different buttons, you use jquery to assign the data to the fields.

For example:

```
<scricpt>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#profilebutton1').on('click', function () { CASE1() });
    jQuery('#profilebutton2').on('click', function () { CASE2() });
});

function CASE1() {
    $('#firstname').val("John")
    $('#lastname').val("Snow")
    $('#age').val("45")
}
function CASE2() {
    $('#firstname').val("Joe")
    $('#lastname').val("Schmo")
    $('#age').val("23")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Wellspring. I am going to try that out and see if it works. However, is there a way to click the profile button while remaining on the same page and just display the profiles with radio buttons? Whether that be a small text field that comes up or etc. Thanks